# Extrude Between wrong on the edge using ArcScene

Tags: arcgis-desktop, 3d-analyst, arcscene, tin

I'm trying to extrude between two Tins which are equally shaped. However if Extrude Between those tins using input feature created by minimal_bounding from one of them I get a strange error that two sides of my extruded block are inclined and thus the result is wrong (see images below).

I have absolutely no clue what could be the reason.

Here are some images to illustrate the problem:

[a http://imageshack.us/a/img833/4924/48164856.jpg](http://imageshack.us/a/img833/4924/48164856.jpg)
[b http://imageshack.us/a/img801/706/94039199.jpg](http://imageshack.us/a/img801/706/94039199.jpg)

I'm using ArcScene with ArcGIS Desktop 10.1.

This question can also be found on:
http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/77930-Extrude-between-wrong-on-the-edge-ArcScene?p=273925#post273925

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With help from Esri I was able to solve the problem with a workaround:

Using a polygon which is slightly smaller produces a multipatch which does not have a dip. In addition I figured out that the point position from the nodes for both tins should be at the same x,y position to get good results of the extrusion.

The bug is listed at http://support.esri.com/en/bugs/nimbus/TklNMDY5MDQw